# Unique Permutations Of 'LYLY' If Each Permutation Must Contain 'LY'

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I recently started working on permutations, and came across this problem:

> > **How many possible unique permutations of 'LYLY' contain 'LY'?**

I understand the basic method of solving this type of problem:

> n! , where n = number of letters

And if there are repeating symbols:

> n!/n<sub>1</sub>! * n<sub>2</sub>! * n<sub>3</sub>!  . . .* n<sub>k</sub>! , where n = number of letters

However, I cannot solve this problem, because I do not know the method of finding the number of permutations if there are *multiple copies* of the letters that can make up 'LY'.

So, how, and with what method, would you solve this(or this type of/similar) problem? I have tried searching for a solution or other question, but I cannot seem to find a solid, valid solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In this case it is easier to find how many do(es) not contain $LY$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular case is fairly simple to solve by examination, but for more complicated case you probably want to work with inclusion-exclusion, where you make an initial estimate of cases, then remove cases that are double-counted and (if needed) restore cases that were triple-counted and hence removed twice in the previous step, etc.

So, as an example of this, we can first arrange the elements with an $\fbox{LY}$ composite element and two solo letters of $L$ and $Y$, giving $3!=6$ arrangements. However we can see that double-counting is possible, so we can arrange two composite elements $\fbox{LY}$ and subtract off the result. However there is a danger here - because the elements are identical, there is only **one** arrangement of these two elements, not two. So subtract off this single double-counted option and you have the result, $6-1=5$.

By the same process, for example, arranging $LAYLA$ to include $LA$ somewhere would have $4!-3!/2$ options.

Comment: Also, of course, you can always just count them: $\sf LYLY, LYYL, LLYY, YLYL, YLLY$

Comment: @GrahamKemp Yes, as I say in the opening sentence :-)